# running sql on link click

Tags: php, mysql, sql

please view the following code.

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 


<tr> 
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></td> 
      <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?></td> 
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['starthol'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['endhol'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['days'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
    <td><a href="#">Approve</a></td> 
    <td><a href="*">Reject</a></td> 

</tr>
```

This populate a table from a previously ran sql query. Basically, when approve is clicked,I want to run an SQL query that uses the id of the the row and updates a column in the table called "active".

```
UPDATE holidays 
SET active = "active"
WHERE holid = getid
```

Any advice on how to do this?

I am a php novice, so please go easy on me. Thank you.

Comment: you can use ajax to send back the status to backend and run sql query there.

Comment: You should search for tutorial on ajax

Answer (score 1):

You should consider learning how to [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.pos.php)

```
<td><a href="active.php?id=?"<?php echo $row['id']; ?> >Approve</a></td>
```

Server side code active.php(sample dont copy paste you must use `post` to update db state not `get` also mysql_* depricated)

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
mysql_query("UPDATE holidays 
SET active = 'active'
WHERE holid = $id")or die(mysql_error());
header('location:listingpage.php?msg=approved');
```

Comment: after updating most probably you need to redirect to listing page

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get your query to run and return data?  Assuming you have data, you will want to update your `foreach()` loop.  If you want the loop to work over more than one line, you'll have to use curly braces (`{  }`)

So your code would look more like:

```
<?php foreach($rows as $row) { ?> 

 ...

<?php } ?>
```